# Downloading file through SSH with a "proxy" machine inbetween

Tags: ssh, scp

I need to download a file from machine C to machine A. To do that, I need to login to machine B (I am doing this using `scp`), as I cannot access C directly from A.

Would it be possible to download a file from C to A with a single command or a script?

Comment: I guess you are using `ssh` to login to machine B not `scp`.

Answer (score 3):

If you can access from machine B to A & C,

Newer version of `scp` support the `-3` switch, which allow you copy a file between 2 remote machines.

```
 -3      Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local host.  Without this option the data is copied directly between the two remote hosts.  Note that this option disables the
         progress meter.
```

---

```
$ scp -3 user1@C:/file user2@A:/file
```

Comment: Didn't you forget to add the '-3' in the example command? Also, the question mentions C -> A, not A -> C.

Answer (score 2):

If you have configured SSH-access on all machines, you can setup SSH-tunnel via machine B.
First step:

```
[user@A ~]$ ssh -f -L LOCALPORT:IP_ADDR_C:22 user_at_B@IP_ADDR_B
```

Key `-f` put `ssh` to background just before command execution.
Good idea to use `-N` key.
From `man ssh`:

```
-N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just forwarding ports (protocol version 2 only).
```

Now you can use `scp`:

```
[user@A ~]$ scp -P LOCALPORT user_at_C@localhost:<your_file_at_C> <local_file>
```

For example, we'll download file `test.txt` from user's `me` homedir at machine `192.168.1.1` placed behind machine `host.example.com`:

```
ssh -f -N -L 2222:192.168.1.1:22 me@host.example.com
scp -P 2222 me@localhost:~/test.txt .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can establish an `ssh` tunnel from B to C, then from A `scp` to B's port, where the tunnel serves to download the file. There are many information pages, Google for them, one of the first searches took me [here](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple way to do this!

1. First connect to the gateway:

   ```
   ssh user@B
   ```
2. Launch the copy C -> A

   ```
   ssh user@C "dd if=/path/source/file" | ssh user@A "dd of=/path/destination/file"
   ```

If you want to get rid of the messages written by `dd` on stderr, either use the option `status=none` if your version of `dd` supports this, or use `2> /dev/null`.

Note that there is a bug in the version 8.4 of `dd` causing `status=none` not to work even if this is present in the documentation.

Comment: But this is only useful when the scp version on the gateway doesn't support the '-3' option of scp (Rabin's answer).