# How to transfer files between two servers with a server in the middle?

Tags: ssh, scp, ssh-tunneling

I'm usually used to `scp` but this time to access the source server I need to `ssh` to a first machine then do another `ssh` from this server to access a local machine.
How to transfer files from this machine to my machine? because it's not directly accessible.
Can I use the machine in the middle as a "proxy" for my transfers?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296194/100397

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/143733/100397

Answer (score 0):

Hi I believe that following question - [Downloading file through SSH with a "proxy" machine inbetween](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143733/downloading-file-through-ssh-with-a-proxy-machine-inbetween) might help you.

You probably need `-3` parameter more information as always can be found in manual `man 1 scp`.